# How to do a proof of sequences?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Prove that for all $k > 100$, the quantity $\frac {1}{k^2}$ is in the interval $(0, 0.0001)$.

Comment: What's bigger: 1/2 or 1/5?

Comment: So if we pick $k = 10^{100}$, getting $\frac{1}{10^{100}}$. Then that is within the interval $(0,0.0001)$? This question seems like it has to have another constraint from above for $k$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "direct" approach is fine: $$k\ge 100\Rightarrow k^2\ge10000\iff \frac{1}{k^2}\le\frac{1}{10000}.$$ $\frac{1}{k^2}>0$ since $k^2>0$ so we conclude $\frac{1}{k^2}\in(0,\frac{1}{10000}).$

Answer (score 0):

An exmple of how to write it. Assume that any reader will not require you to prove that $a>b>0 \implies 0<a^{-1}<b^{-1}.$

$\forall k\in \Bbb R$

$(k>10^2\to k>10^2>0\to k^2>10^4>0\to 0<(k^2)^{-1}<(10^2)^{-1}\to 0<k^{-2}<10^{-4}).$

I used $\to$ for $\implies$ to fit it into one line. Can't fit the $\forall$ part into the same line.